# work more cleverly, not harder

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

The following sixteen words can be divided into four groups. Each group is of four words connected by a theme; the four themes are also related to one another.

ANTIC ASKEW BATTERS CARPER CASH CHALK CLEVERLY HARDER JACK LINES OH PATE REED SANDERS STRIDE TESTER

Comment: Was this puzzle created entirely by you? it seems very similar to [this](https://www.nytimes.com/games/connections).

Comment: @BlueHerring This is a 'connecting wall' type puzzle, a format which pre-dates the NYT's 'Connections' puzzle by 15 years, having originated in the BBC quiz show [Only Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Connect), first broadcast in 2008.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The theme of the themes is:

> Current Anglosphere Politicians

Group 1:

> United States Senators
>  [Tom CARPER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Carper), [Jack REED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Reed_(Rhode_Island_politician)), [Bernie SANDERS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernie_Sanders), [Jon TESTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Tester)

Group 2:

> UK Cabinet Ministers
>  [Alex CHALK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Chalk), [James CLEVERLY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Cleverly), [Alister JACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alister_Jack), [Mel STRIDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Stride)

Group 3:

> Canadian Senators
>  [Denise BATTERS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denise_Batters), [Peter HARDER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Harder_(politician)), [Victor OH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Oh), [Kim PATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Pate)

Group 4:

> Australian Senators
>  [Alex ANTIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Antic), [Wendy ASKEW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendy_Askew), [Michaelia CASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelia_Cash), [Sue LINES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sue_Lines)

Comment: Well done! (Not so important, but your group 1 is actually rot13(pbzzvggrr punvecrbcyr) and your group 2 is rot13(frpergnevrf bs fgngr).)